# How can i take only one finger swerve input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My project is a Runner game where character constantly moves forward and if player slides left or right, character moves that position too. But in mobile, if i slide with one finger and touch with my other finger in the mean time, character starts to take 2 inputs and move wrong directions.

This is my code below:

```
private void Update(){
float newz = transform.position.z + movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
float newx = 0, swipeDelta = 0;
      
        if(Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            swipeDelta = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x / Screen.width;
        }

        newx = transform.position.x + swipeDelta * 5f *Time.deltaTime;

        transform.position = new Vector3(newx, transform.position.y, newz);

}
```

I have set Input.touchCount to 1 because i want it to get only 1 finger input but it did not work. What should i do to make it work with one finger and make it accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `Input.touchCount == 1` to `Input.touchCount > 0` did not solve my problem.
I solved it by adding this line of code in the PlayerController script's Start function:

```
Input.multiTouchEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

From your code it seems that as soon as you touch with second finger it will just not read location of your first finger.

*Input.touchCount == 1* in your if statement looks like a problem for me, it means that if statement will only execute if you have a single finger on your screen. if you change it to *Input.touchCount > 0* it will execute even if there are more fingers on the screens and should work correctly since you are already only taking one input with *Input.GetTouch(0)*.

```
private void Update(){
float newz = transform.position.z + movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
float newx = 0, swipeDelta = 0;
  
    if(Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        swipeDelta = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x / Screen.width;
    }

    newx = transform.position.x + swipeDelta * 5f *Time.deltaTime;

    transform.position = new Vector3(newx, transform.position.y, newz);

}
```

Comment: In that case you should take the [`Touch.fingerId`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-fingerId.html) into account though! The `GetTouch(0)` is **not** guaranteed to return the same `Touch` instance across multiple frames.